# Переменная $content

Tags: переменные, yii

Здравствуйте.

Можете разжевать новичку. В Yii есть переменная `$content`, которая хранит вид. Пытаюсь понять, как это работает и как в переменную записали содержимое файла, хочу попробовать повторить подобное (для опыта), не могу понять. ( Хоть и пытаюсь следить по коду, но всё равно не могу понять. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изучайте этот [кусок](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/base/View.php#L320-L328). Функции, написаные тут, достаточно хорошо расписаны в документации.

Comment: Благодарю, всё стало понятно :))